# Looking for a 3D function that traces positive x and y axes with a parabola

Tags: functions, optimization, 3d

I'm designing a loss function for an optimization problem.

My requirements for this function are:

- If only x is small, the function should be small
- If only y is small, the function should be small
- If both x and y are large, the function should be large
- If both x and y are small, the function should be large

In my mind this function looks something like this:

[https://imgur.com/gMz7HAa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMjRP.png)

[https://imgur.com/iiVHmut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITJBo.png)

Note how the function minima avoids the origin to comply with the 4th requirement.
The x, and y values will always be positive, so I only care about the first quadrant.

The best I could come up with is
$$f(x, y) = \sqrt{(\frac{1}{0.05*x})-y)^6}$$
which results in a function that looks like this

[https://i.imgur.com/4mc8rIK.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8xLc.png)

[https://i.imgur.com/2daiCHX.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w6aL.png)

The problem is that the minima gets very "thin" along the y-axis compared to the x-axis.

I'm aware that “large” and “small” are very vague terms. I only need the structure of the function, I can tune its size later myself.

What function can represent what I'm looking for?

Comment: Not really related to math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you want domain $x,y>0$, by taking logs, you can reword your question as

- if $x,y>0$ or $x,y<0$, then $f>0$
- if $x<0,y>0$ or $x>0,y<0$, then $f<0$

From this it's clear that $f=xy$ should work. After taking exponents:
$$
f = e^{\log x \log y}
$$

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!